# Why Ajax is triggering 500 internal error in django?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

Does anyone know why I am getting 500 internal error when I try to call an Ajax function? I tried to send the response from `view.py` to `Ajax function` in 2 ways: `JsonResponse` (see else from view.py) and also with `HttpResponse` (see if from View.py).

My Hmtl form does have a csrf_token, so I added the header in ajax function, but still got 500 internal erorr. The data is saved into database but the response is not sent to ajax function.

**View.py**

```
## Ajax
@login_required
def SubmitModal(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.POST['Text']
        date = request.POST['DatePicker']
        time = request.POST['TimePicker']
        
        T = SText()
        
        T.User = request.user
        T.Text = text
        T.STime = date + ' ' + time
        T.save()

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success': True}), content_type="application/json")
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'success': False})
```

**file that contains ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Show the modal window when a button is clicked
    $('#open-modal').click(function () {
        $('#modal').modal('show');
    });

    // Close the modal window when a button is clicked
    $('.close-modal').click(function () {
        $('#modal').modal('hide');
    });
    
    // Handle the form submission
    $('#modal-form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from being submitted
        var formData = $(this).serialize(); // Get the form data
        // Submit the form data to the server using an AJAX request
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/submit/',
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    $('#success-message').show();
                } else {
                    $('#error-message').show();
                }
            },
             error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
        });
        $(".textarea-input")[0].value = '';
        $(".date-input")[0].value = '';
        $(".time-input")[0].value = '';
    });
});
```

Comment: A 500 error means there was an unhandled exception on the **server**. You'll have to look at server logs, or something like that. It may have been caused by parameters your client sent, but it's not practical to debug the problem that way unless the parameter error(s) are obvious (to you).

Comment: I am using localhost atm. Will have a look over logs. Thanks

Comment: Your "file that contains ajax", is it its own separate javascript file or is it inside your html template ?

Comment: @AlexanderFreyr it is outside of html template.

Answer (score 1):

If you're reproducing this in a non-production environment, you can set `DEBUG=True` in the settings file. Then when you make the call from your browser, the response will include details about what the issue is. You can also set the `ADMINS` variable to send exception tracebacks to the specified emails when they're encountered. More details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#admins).

You can view the data being sent and received in the developer tools of the browser you are using.

Comment: I already have that `DEBUG` setting on `True' but it doesn't trigger me any informations. I see the error when I copy paste the `js file` into console. Then I click on submit then I get the error.

Comment: @PaulViorel Try checking the "network" tab after doing that, and see if the call receiving a 500 has anything information in the response section

Comment: Unfortunately nothing is showed on network tab after I click on submit button

Comment: Interesting, do you still observe the change in the database? Also, make sure that you have "all" selected for the request type.

Comment: Yea. All the inputs are added into database. I found the problem. I just removed last 3 lines of code, those that resets the input values (.textarea-input, .date-input,.time-input) and it worked perfectly the ajax call. Probably should add those lines inside of "success"

Comment: Yep, just moved those 3 lines that reset the value inside of succes, and it worked smoothly.